# Simple representation of measurable maps w.r.t. different measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measurable space and $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ a bounded and measurable function. Let $\mathbb P_1,\dots,\mathbb P_N$ be any probability measures. It is well known, that we have the simple representation $$f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k,i}\cdot 1_{A_{k,i}}\ \ \mathbb P_i-a.s.$$ for each $i=1,\dots,N$, where
$(a_{k,i})_{k\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb R$ and $(A_{k,i})_{k\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathcal F$. Can we always find $(b_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb R$ and $B_k\in\mathcal F$ such that $$f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_{k}\cdot 1_{B_{k}} \mathbb\ \ \mathbb P_i-a.s.$$ for all $i=1,\dots,N$?

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with the existence of such a representation. Is it related to the fact that $f_n\to f$ everywhere where $f_n$ is a certain sequence of simple functions?

Comment: See the following link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function. Through your question, I realize that the representation can be written independently of the underlying measure, and since $f$ is bounded, the convergence of simple functions that you mentioned, is uniform. But the function to which the simple functions converge are dependent on the underlying measure...

Comment: I didn't get from your comment, what is dependent and what is not. I know about a representation as a limit of simple functions, which does not require mentioning measure at all. However, I haven't seen the representation as an infinite sum. In the linked article there's nothing about that. Which independent representation did you realize through my previous question, and which functions are dependent on the measure?

Comment: You can define $A_1=\{x\mid f(x)\geq 1\}$ and inductively $A_k=\{x\mid f(x)\geq \frac{1}{k}+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{j}1_{A_j}\}$, $k=2,3,\dots.$ Then we have $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}1_{A_k}$, no? But you are right in the sense, that this is independent of the measure...I first thought that the measurable sets $A_k$ depend on the measure...

Comment: I haven't heard of such construction, and it seems to be correct. Anyways, it's independent of the measure, and the convergence (provided it holds) neither depends on the measure.